# webBrowse control and Double Clicking

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio-2015, webbrowser-control, kendo-chart

I've been asked to create a very simple windows application whereby the only item on the form is a webBrowse control. I set some size elements and navigate to the URL desired. Basically it's a custom Kiosk Mode.

The problem is the webpage has features which require double clicking and these work fine in IE11 but don't in the kiosk application. I've been trying to research and play with this all morning to no avail. The best I've got so far is:

```
private void mainBrowse_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    mainBrowse.Document.Body.AttachEventHandler("ondblclick", Document_DoubleClick);            
}

void Document_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.mainBrowse.Document.GetElementFromPoint(MousePosition).InvokeMember("doubleclick");

    //MessageBox.Show("double click detected");
}
```

The messagebox fires (when not commented out) but I can't get it to pass through the event to the underlying page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I realised this was a Kendo Chart (not a technology I'm familiar with) I added this to my searches and found this page:

https://www.telerik.com/forums/gantt-does-not-render-correctly-in-winforms-webbrowser-control

Off the back of this I created an event for _Navigated and injected the necessary script that it recommended:

```
private void mainBrowse_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlDocument doc = mainBrowse.Document;
    HtmlElement head = doc.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    HtmlElement s = doc.CreateElement("script");
    s.SetAttribute("text", "window.MSPointerEvent = null;window.PointerEvent = null; ");
    head.AppendChild(s);
}
```

This worked, which was a relief.